# How to fill the first date in the column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I  have a `df`:

```
dates   values
2020-01-01 00:15:00 38.61487
2020-01-01 00:30:00 36.905204
2020-01-01 00:45:00 35.136584
2020-01-01 01:00:00 33.60378
2020-01-01 01:15:00 32.306791999999994
2020-01-01 01:30:00 31.304574
```

I am creating a new column named `start` as follows:

```
df = df.rename(columns={'dates': 'end'})
df['start']= df['end'].shift(1)
```

When I do this, I get the following:

```
end values  start
2020-01-01 00:15:00 38.61487    NaT
2020-01-01 00:30:00 36.905204   2020-01-01 00:15:00
2020-01-01 00:45:00 35.136584   2020-01-01 00:30:00
2020-01-01 01:00:00 33.60378    2020-01-01 00:45:00
2020-01-01 01:15:00 32.306791999999994  2020-01-01 01:00:00
2020-01-01 01:30:00 31.304574   2020-01-01 01:15:00
```

I want to fill that `NaT` value with

```
2020-01-01 00:00:00
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with `datetime`s, e.g. by [`Timestamp`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html):

```
df['start']= df['end'].shift().fillna(pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01'))
```

Or if pandas 0.24+ with `fill_value` parameter:

```
df['start']= df['end'].shift(fill_value=pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01'))
```

If all datetimes are regular, always difference `15 minutes` is possible subtracting by [`offsets.DateOffset`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html):

```
df['start']= df['end'] - pd.offsets.DateOffset(minutes=15)
print (df)
                  end     values               start
0 2020-01-01 00:15:00  38.614870 2020-01-01 00:00:00
1 2020-01-01 00:30:00  36.905204 2020-01-01 00:15:00
2 2020-01-01 00:45:00  35.136584 2020-01-01 00:30:00
3 2020-01-01 01:00:00  33.603780 2020-01-01 00:45:00
4 2020-01-01 01:15:00  32.306792 2020-01-01 01:00:00
5 2020-01-01 01:30:00  31.304574 2020-01-01 01:15:00
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it directly without using `fillna()` ? I mean the difference can be taken from the second row and it can be used to calculate the starting value?

Comment: @reinhardt - `d = df['end']
df['start']= df['end'].shift(fill_value=d.iat[0] - (d.iat[1] - d.iat[0]))` should working, but not so nice

Answer (score 0):

How about that?

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['end'])
df.loc[:, 'end'] = pd.date_range(start=pd.Timestamp(2019,1,1,0,15), end=pd.Timestamp(2019,1,2), freq='15min')
df.loc[:, 'start'] = df.loc[:, 'end'].shift(1)

delta = df.loc[df.index[3], 'end'] - df.loc[df.index[2], 'end']
df.loc[df.index[0], 'start'] = df.loc[df.index[1], 'start'] - delta

df

    end     start
0   2019-01-01 00:15:00     2019-01-01 00:00:00
1   2019-01-01 00:30:00     2019-01-01 00:15:00
2   2019-01-01 00:45:00     2019-01-01 00:30:00
3   2019-01-01 01:00:00     2019-01-01 00:45:00
4   2019-01-01 01:15:00     2019-01-01 01:00:00
...     ...     ...
91  2019-01-01 23:00:00     2019-01-01 22:45:00
92  2019-01-01 23:15:00     2019-01-01 23:00:00
93  2019-01-01 23:30:00     2019-01-01 23:15:00
94  2019-01-01 23:45:00     2019-01-01 23:30:00
95  2019-01-02 00:00:00     2019-01-01 23:45:00
```